# Cant Pop up a new tab using Javascript in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Hi I want when I get login a new tab get open but doesnt work already... My code is here... Any Idea? I get log but the new tab doesn´t get open

```
public function login(){

            $correo = Input::get('correo');
            $contra = Input::get('contraseña');

            $user = DB::select('select * from usuarios where CORREO_USUARIO = ? and CONTRASENA = ? limit 1', array($correo, $contra));
            if($user){
                Session::put('correoUsuario', $correo); 
                echo "<script language='javascript'>window.open('https://hangouts.google.com', '_blank');</script>";
                return Redirect::to('/');
            }
            return Redirect::to('Login');
        }
```

Comment: most browsers will stop that happening by defult

Comment: Yes that's just not going to work in modern (post-2010) browsers.

Comment: Oh thanks... any other way to do it?

Comment: `window.open()` will only work inside a callback from a user-interaction event, which usually means "click".

Comment: ok im gonna do it in other way thank you all

Comment: perhaps not attempting to annoy the user with a new tab, is  the best approach

Comment: Try adding a pure html and css solution where instead of echoing a script to open a window maybe a div with a class of `window` and style in CSS? But opening a browser window will be blocked by the browser

Answer (score 1):

If you're still looking for an answer:

load a view with Javascript file in it, and you can use jQuery's

```
 $(document).load(function(){
 //your popup code here
  // follwed by redirect code
});
```